# Preventing SQL Injection by using Bound Paramaters / Prepared Statements

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sql-injection, android-cursor

Good Morning World,

I'm in the process of making a few small changes to source code and it has been brough to my attention that I've exposed myself to being vulnerable to SQL Injection in my current implementation. I apologize if this is a bit of a noob question - but what would be the best practice / method of preventing such an attack using the example below? (I'll reformat my other code using the same method - I'd just like to see how this might be done in this instance)

### Source Example:

```
public class EventUtils {

public static long getEventId(Context context,long msgId) {
    long eventId = -1;
    Message msg = Message.restoreMessageWithId(context, msgId);
    if(msg != null) {
        PackedString info = new PackedString(msg.mMeetingInfo);
        long startTime = Utility.parseEmailDateTimeToMillis(info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_DTSTART));
        long endTime = Utility.parseEmailDateTimeToMillis(info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_DTEND));
        String title = info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_TITLE);

        String[] projection = new String[]{ Events._ID };
        String selectionClause = Events.DTSTART + " = '" + startTime + "' AND "
                + Events.DTEND + " = '" + endTime + "' AND "
                + Events.TITLE + " = '" + title + "'";
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selectionClause, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                eventId = cursor.getLong(0);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return eventId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified query string (here you set the parameter **placeholders**):

```
String selectionClause = Events.DTSTART + " = ? AND "
    + Events.DTEND + " = ? AND "
    + Events.TITLE + " = ?";
```

Then pass the parameters as a string array (will replace the placeholders, respecting the **same order*):

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
      projection, selectionClause, new String[]{startTime, endTime, title}, null);
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I do have one small problem though. I'm getting an error stating: FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM view_events WHERE (lastSynced = 0 AND (dtstart = '1417815000000' AND dtend = '1417818600000' AND title = 'User's'))

...which I believe is due to an apostrophe in the title field - is there anything I might be able to do to resolve this - or should I post a separate question?

Comment: You can double the apostrophe (**''**). Weird, because this is done during the parameter binding.

Comment: I don't see how / where to double the apostrophe (it is being pulled from the title of an email - so I'll need to remove it when parsing it out) http://pastebin.com/CNVT3e26

Comment: `TITLE` is a string... So what's hard in doing `TITLE = TITLE.replace("'", "''");`?

Comment: I'd say nothing... however I still get the fatal error and an apostrophe when debugging when I attempt to do so: http://pastebin.com/5TDcMcmz

Comment: Weird. You could try combining these 2 instructions into 1: `String title = info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_TITLE);
            title = title.replace("'", "''");` so: `String title = info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_TITLE).replace("'", "''");`

Comment: It is beyond bizarre... 

I've tried it as you suggested and the value of title after stepping over the line String title = info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_TITLE).replace("'", "''"); is still: User's (the apostrophe is still there)

http://pastebin.com/sgDU9DTe

Comment: Yes. **Doubling the apostrophe** is meant **to insert it** into the database. Maybe I misunderstood your intention completely. Did you want to **remove it**, instead?

Comment: Ideally - I'd like to keep it in the database - I'm simply trying to avoid this fatal error I'm getting when using the code as shown in the previous pastebin: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM view_events WHERE (lastSynced = 0 AND (dtstart = '1417815000000' AND dtend = '1417818600000' AND title = 'User's'))

Comment: Well, after the replacement, it should read: `SELECT _id FROM view_events WHERE (lastSynced = 0 AND (dtstart = '1417815000000' AND dtend = '1417818600000' AND title = 'User''s'))` - Therefore giving no more errors. Now, in your latest pastebin... paste I don't see the **replace** statement.

Comment: The title is being parsed from the subject of the email so it could contain user's admin's basically any word with an apostrophe in it - so I need to be able to remove any instance of an apostrophe - which is why your answer seemed logical - I just don't understand why it isn't working as such http://pastebin.com/sgDU9DTe

Comment: Can you do a `System.out.println(title);` after this line `String title = info.get(MeetingInfo.MEETING_TITLE).replace("'", "''");`, please? It will print the transformed (?) title in the logcat window.

Comment: No, seriously. This is not what I asked.